# Need a map reduce function in mongo using php

Tags: php, mongodb, mapreduce

Need a map reduce function by mongo  in php

This my mongo structure

```
[_id] => MongoId Object (
    [$id] => 4fcf2f2313cfcd2454500000d
)
[id] => 454
[table] => people
[news] => Array (
    [03-06-2012] => 2
    [04-06-2012] => 3
    [05-06-2012] => 5
    [06-06-2012] => 4
)
```

Here I try to sum the array news with below code,

```
    $map = new MongoCode('function() { emit(this.news, 1); }');
    $reduce = new MongoCode('function(previous, current) {
                    var count = 0;
                    for (index in current) {
                        count = count + current[index];
                    }
                    return count;
                }');

    $sales = $db->command(array(
        'mapreduce' => 'mycollection',
        'map' => $map,
        'reduce' => $reduce,
        'query' => array('table' => 'people'),
        'out'  => 'news'
    ));

    //pr($sales);exit;

    $users = $db->selectCollection($sales['result'])->find();

    foreach ($users as $user) {
        //echo "{$user['_id']} had {$user['value']} sale(s).\n";
        pr($user);
    }
```

When `pr($user)`

```
Array
(
    [_id] => Array
    (
        [04-06-2012] => 0
        [08-06-2012] => 2
        [11-06-2012] => 6
    )

    [value] => 39540
)
```

Where I expected a value will be 8 instead of 39540.

How I can correct this function and how to the add a field sum as array sum of 'news' to original collection(mycollection) ?

I am not familar with map reduce functions in mongo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When calling `emit()`, the first parameter is the key you'll be reducing on (or grouping, for this example). The second parameter is the value being emitted for that key, which can be anything. For your example, you probably mean to emit the sum of all values in the `news` field, using the document's ID as your key:

```
var map = function() {
    var total = 0;
    for (count in this.news) {
        total += count;
    }
    emit(this._id, total);
}
```

In this case, a placeholder reduce function can be used (since each emitted key will be unique, there's very little reduction to be done):

```
var reduce = function(key, values) {
    var total = 0;
    values.forEach(function(v) { total += v; });
    return total;
}
```

However, as I mentioned in the [Google Group post](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/mongodb-user/s1BJq7ftcnw/discussion), you may be better off doing this with pure PHP:

```
$cursor = $collection->find(array(), array('news' => 1));
$cursor->snapshot();

foreach ($cursor as $document) {
    $collection->update(
        array('_id' => $document['_id']),
        array('$set' => array('sum' => array_sum($document['news']))),
        array('multiple' => false)
    );
}
```

With map/reduce, you'd still have to examine its results and update your records. This would avoid the need to execute JavaScript through Mongo, and should be more performant. And if you can utilize $inc to update the sums as the `news` field is modified on a per-document basis, that will be even better. The above snippet would still be useful for initializing `sum` fields across the collection, or correcting any drift if things get out of sync with per-document increments.

Note: see [snapshot()](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/mongodb-user/s1BJq7ftcnw/discussion) in the documentation for the reasoning behind that method call in the example above.

Comment: I followed suming with pure PHP and working fine. But I try to get with map reduce, but new collection is outputting as    `[_id] => MongoId Object (
    [$id] => 4fd8993a13cfcd4e42000000
)
[value] => 0013-06-2012`   where orginal news array is `[news] => Array (
    [13-06-2012] => 1
)` . Whether the snapshot increase the performance ?

Comment: If you're attempting to compute a sum using map/reduce, the value should be an integer sum. In your case, it looks like you are emitting the news date instead of a sum. My example above demonstrates how to calculate a sum using map and reduce functions. Regarding your second question, I'm not aware of any documented performance impact of snapshot but it's reasonable to assume there is some slight overhead involved.

Answer (score 1):

While jmikola's answer gives me wright track to deal with mongo map reduce functions.

I am adding this answer in order to help future visitors.

The following `map-reduce` function works perfectly to my requirement. 
This will sum all values in the news field to new collection called `news` created in command by adding (`"out" => "news"`).

**Map-Reduce Function**

```
$map = new MongoCode('function() {
            var total = 0;
            for (count in this.news) {
            total +=  this.news[count];
            }
            emit(this._id, {id: this.id, total: total});
        }');
$reduce = new MongoCode('function(key, values) {
            var result = {id: null, total: 0};
            values.forEach(function(v) {
            result.id = v.id;
            result.total = v.total;
             });
            return result;
        }');

$sales = $db->command(array(
    'mapreduce' => 'mycollection', // collection name
    'map' => $map,
    'reduce' => $reduce,
    'query' => array('table' => 'people'),
    "out" => "news" // new collection name
));
```

The result will be `news` collection with sum as `total` and `id` of actual document

**Output**

```
[_id] => MongoId Object (
    [$id] => 4fd8993a13cfcd4e42000000
)
[value] => Array (
    [id] => 454
    [total] => 14
)
```